# How do i disable the "Touchpad on" notification appearing on my screen

Tags: windows-10, touchpad

The image attached is basically what it looks like.
I would screenshot it, but it goes away when I try to.

It does get really annoying, trying to play video-games and this appears and kicks me from the game.

I've tried disabling my touchpad but the notification still pops up.

What the notification looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a Synaptic TouchPad, this will disable the notification :

- Open *Settings > System > Notifications & Actions*
- Under "Get notifications from these apps", find Synaptic TouchPad
- Set it to Off.

Comment: My touchpad is actually just a blank square, and that doesn't appear either when I go to Notifications & Actions.

Comment: Have you tried to find the process that issues this notification? You could perhaps use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and drag-release the bullseye over it.

Comment: I do know how the notification does get issued, which is literally by touching the touchpad, and the touchpad isn't centered on my laptop, so basically my hand is on it 99% of the time.

Comment: Knowing the process that issues it, you could either disable its notifications, like in my answer, or disable it another way.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the help!

Comment: It worked, thank you for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. Which process was it that issued the notification?